# qooxdoo : Rotate Button along its center

Tags: qooxdoo

I have a `qx.ui.form.Button`. I would like it to rotate 180 degree ( i.e. upside down ) along its center when I click the button. (I'm working on `qx.Desktop` )

```
var btn = new qx.ui.form.Button(null, "myproject/button.png");
btn.addListener("click", function () {
  // which function should I use ?
});
```

The rotation should have animation, i.e. rotate clockwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

qooxdoo does not have transformations build in the widget layer itself but it offers a way to animate / rotate dom elements. So you have to get the container element of the button and start a animation on that:

```
var el = btn.getContainerElement().getDomElement();
qx.bom.element.Animation.animate(el, {
  duration: 1000, timing: "ease", keep: 100, keyFrames : {
    0: {rotate: "0deg"},       // ["0deg"] for flipping effect
    100 : {rotate : "180deg"}  // ["180deg"] for flipping effect
  }
});
```

Check out the documentation of the animate function to see how this code works:
[http://demo.qooxdoo.org/current/apiviewer/#qx.bom.element.Animation~animate](http://demo.qooxdoo.org/current/apiviewer/#qx.bom.element.Animation%7Eanimate)

And [here](http://demo.qooxdoo.org/current/playground/#%7B%22code%22%3A%22%252F%252F%2520Create%2520a%2520button%250Avar%2520button1%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.form.Button(%2522First%2520Button%2522%252C%2520%2522icon%252F22%252Fapps%252Finternet-web-browser.png%2522)%253B%250A%250A%252F%252F%2520Document%2520is%2520the%2520application%2520root%250Avar%2520doc%2520%253D%2520this.getRoot()%253B%250A%250A%252F%252F%2520Add%2520button%2520to%2520document%2520at%2520fixed%2520coordinates%250Adoc.add(button1%252C%250A%257B%250A%2520%2520left%2520%253A%2520100%252C%250A%2520%2520top%2520%2520%253A%252050%250A%257D)%253B%250A%250A%252F%252F%2520Add%2520an%2520event%2520listener%250Abutton1.addListener(%2522execute%2522%252C%2520function(e)%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520var%2520el%2520%253D%2520button1.getContainerElement().getDomElement()%253B%250A%2520%2520qx.bom.element.Animation.animate(el%252C%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520duration%253A%25201000%252C%2520timing%253A%2520%2522ease%2522%252C%2520keep%253A%2520100%252C%2520keyFrames%2520%253A%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%25200%253A%2520%257Brotate%253A%2520%255B%25220deg%2522%255D%257D%252C%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520100%2520%253A%2520%257Brotate%2520%253A%2520%255B%2522180deg%2522%255D%257D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%250A%2520%2520%257D)%253B%250A%257D)%253B%22%2C%20%22mode%22%3A%22ria%22%7D) is a working playground sample.

Comment: very close to what I want. What if I want to rotate clockwise instead of flipping effect? and will this animation fail to support older IE ?